# need some help in formating the query

Tags: sql, oracle

Looking for some help in modifying the below query,

### Query:

```
select distinct 
      upper(
        regexp_replace(
          regexp_substr(asset,'@([^\.-]+)[so]?[\.-]',1,1,'i',1)
          ,'[so]$','')
      ) AS instancename,
      Asset 
    from hsbc_csmip_dbprotect
```

### Current Output:

```
Asset                                   |Instancename
----------------------------------------+------------
EMS                                     |   NULL
IGASDBL_11G                             |   NULL
IGASHLEL_11G                            |   NULL
LMSPEGA1@SSUML527                       |   NULL
ABACOGP@abacogp@ora-abacogp.de.hsbc     |ABACOGP@ORA
ABM00@frlooraprda1.systems.uk.hsbc      |FRLOORAPRDA1
ABMHIST@trabmora01h.hbtr.adroot.hsbc    |TRABMORA01H
```

### Desired Output:

```
Asset                                   |Instancename
----------------------------------------+------------
EMS                                     |EMS
IGASDBL_11G                             |IGASDBL
IGASHLEL_11G                            |IGASHLEL
LMSPEGA1@SSUML527                       |SSUML527
ABACOGP@abacogp@ora-abacogp.de.hsbc     |ABACOGP
ABM00@frlooraprda1.systems.uk.hsbc      |FRLOORAPRDA1
ABMHIST@trabmora01h.hbtr.adroot.hsbc    |TRABMORA01H
```

Comment: Are you saying that the query you've included above produces the output you included?

Comment: it's producing me the output as like the first table but I would like to see the output like in the second table.

Comment: Could you explain what should be a result in these cases: `Xxxx@yyy@zzz.qqq` and `xxx.yyy@zzz` and `xxx.yyy.zzz` ?

Comment: Just regarding your title: Whatever you need help with, it seems to be about the query **output** (rather than simply "the query"). And **formatting** the query, or query output? What do you mean by "formatting"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this works:

```
 select distinct upper(regexp_substr(SUBSTR(asset, INSTR(asset, '@')+1),'[^-@\.]+',1,1)) AS instancename,Asset 
from hsbc_csmip_dbprotect;
```